# Getting an element out of an XML Object With PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am completely stuck on this issue so your help is greatly appreciated!

I simply need to pull the ValidationCode out of this existing XML object.

Here's is what I get when I do:

print_r($response);

TheResponse Object ( [ResponseText] => xxxxxxxxx [ResponseXml] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [ValidationRequest] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [AccountSid] => xxxxxxxx [PhoneNumber] => +15555555555 [FriendlyName] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [ValidationCode] => 601532 ) ) [HttpStatus] => 200 [Url] => https://api.dddddd.com//2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxx/OutgoingCallerIds [QueryString] => [IsError] => [ErrorMessage] => )

How in the WORLD do I access that Validation Code using php?

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$code = $response->ResponseXml->ValidationRequest->ValidationCode;
```

Comment: Life saver! Thank you friend. I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ValidationCode=$response->ResponseXml->ValidationRequest->ValidationCode;
```